# jQuery Cloudinary plugin doesn't initiate automatic uploading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, cloudinary

I am attaching **Cloudinary jQuery plugin** to my site but nothing works.
So I've created empty project and tried to run plugin there.

My form (the button says 'Browse... file isn't chosen')
[image: hh]

When I hit Browse button I can choose the file, but after file is chosen the label 'file isn't chosen' still there. 
Also, **after hitting the button and choosing the file, Cloudinary plugin should automatically initiate uploading to my cloud**, but in my cloud there are no any files.

Here is my View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cloudinary.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.cloudinary.config({"api_key": "558288263223776", "cloud_name": "ubakip-ru", "private_cdn": false});
</script>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload_form">
    <input class="cloudinary-fileupload"
           data-cloudinary-field="photo_id"
           data-form-data=""
           data-url="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ubakip-ru/image/upload"
           name="file"
           type="file"
           id="uploadinput">
</form>
    <script>
        var data = {
            "timestamp": @WebApplication9.Controllers.HomeController.getTime(),
            "callback": "~/Content/cloudinary_cors.html",
            "signature": "@WebApplication9.Controllers.HomeController.getSignature()",
            "api_key": "558288263223776"
        };
        $('#uploadinput').attr('data-form-data', JSON.stringify(data));
    </script>
```

Here is controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CloudinaryDotNet;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication9.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        static Cloudinary m_cloudinary;

        static HomeController()
        {
            Account acc = new Account("******-ru", "558288263223776", "***************************");
            m_cloudinary = new Cloudinary(acc);
        }

        public static string getSignature()
        {
            return m_cloudinary.Api.SignParameters(new SortedDictionary<string, object>() { { "api_key", "558288263223776" } });
        }

        public static string getTime()
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the project structure:

[image: hh]

Timestamp and signature generating well, I checked many times.

Although, there are no any errors or warnings, and something even works (in Chrome dev-tools F12, when I choose file, input-tag is being highlited by pink color for a second) nothing is going to my cloudinary cloud.

[image: hh]

Comment: P.S.: Sorry, my question is a bit overweighted by pics and code, cause I want to provide maximum info about my problem. I've read through all forums and questions about my problem and tried their solutions, but nothing worked for me.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing any errors in the Console/Network tabs (Under developer tools)?
Can you share a URL to a live webpage where this is demonstrated?

Comment: Yes it is shown here: http://ubakip.ru

Checkd console, it says: **Error 401 Unauthorized POST request**.

Comment: Can you please share the steps I need to do in order to get the specific page that demonstrates this issue? I went to the link you said and I just see a black page there.

Comment: Could you check please once again, just `http://ubakip.ru/` , for me everything works there. (except Cloudinary)

Comment: Thank you, I could see the page now. When you experience errors, you should take a look at the HTTP response headers for more information about the issue. Specifically here, this is returned: `X-Cld-Error:Invalid Signature f3f3659ca515be86f07420afa54621a22822be17. String to sign - 'callback=~/Content/cloudinary_cors.html&timestamp=1463445803'.`. Which means that the signature is incorrect. Can you add the code snippet of how you calculated the signature?

Comment: I calculate the signature with getSignature() method,  which is in the controller's code in my first message. But this method is a replica of method which is inside Api.cs of cloudinary.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Then this is indeed the issue. As the error message says, you must sign the `callback` and the `timestamp` parameters and values. Actually the `api_key` shouldn't be signed. See this for a reference: https://github.com/cloudinary/CloudinaryDotNet/blob/691fe500028a2cf7e0d28b312ebc55ac506d95f0/Cloudinary.Test/ApiTest.cs#L29. Here's some more information: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#creating_api_authentication_signatures